# django annotate on select_related field

Tags: django, annotate, django-select-related

My simplified models:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Price(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField('Product', primary_key=True)
    value = models.DecimalField()

class Cart(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    qnt =  models.IntegerField()
```

I need multiplication of two fields get stored in other field namely `sum` . Why does  `Cart.objects.select_related('product__price').annotate(sum=F('product__price__value') * F('qnt'))` returns nothing?

Replacing `F('')` to `F('value')` returns error

> Cannot resolve keyword 'value' into field. Choices are: cart_id,
>   id, product, product_id, qnt

Comment: I used @property with sum in my model, and solve it. But i want to know same solution using annotate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to multiply Integer Field with Decimal Field. So, it occurs an error. You can try this

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, F, DecimalField


Cart.objects.select_related('product__price').annotate(
    sum= ExpressionWrapper(
        F('product__price__value') * F('qnt'), output_field=DecimalField()))
```

> If the fields that you’re combining are of different types you’ll need to tell Django what kind of field will be returned. Since F() does not directly support output_field you will need to wrap the expression with ExpressionWrapper

Comment: Nice. Thank you. But why i didn't catch exeption for this case? I used try with Exception.

Comment: Which exception occured?

Comment: About combining of types or something else. I want to know, why resuls are empty.